# Have the inventors of Java ever publicly expressed regret about hashCode and equals in class Object?

Tags: java, programming-languages

I was talking to a colleague recently about hashCode and equals being methods in class Object in Java (among other languages). I am from a more theoretical background while my colleague is more of a pragmatic person.

In my opinion it does not make any sense of having the hashCode and equals methods being defined in class Object. While our personal discussion was quite amusing I am more interested in an official retrospective on this subject from the original inventors of java. Have they ever publicly expressed regret about having made the decision? Or have they every explicitly defended their decision against criticism in public?

Public statements from people other than the original developers are also welcome but please only from people with at least some level of authority and notability.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite an answer: but Eric Lippert has expressed he'd do things differently for C# if they started again https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/ and Id think Eric's line of reasoning would hold for Java too

Comment: @jk that is an acceptable answer to me.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as being opinion based. It says right there that I should edit the question so it can be answered wtih facts and citations, but that is exactly what I am asking for. My question specifically asks for citations. How can that be opinion based?

Comment: I think their logic will be that you are asking for the opion of a specific team, which is either opion based or asking for a resource (which is also not allowed, and at least 1 of the close votes was for this). Reddit is probably a better forum for questions like this. alternatively you could change the question to presuppose an alternative design where hashCode is on a hashable interface and ask for the pros and cons of it, that might get through

Comment: So asking for citations from authority figures is not allowed on SO?

Comment: i think it would be considered a resource request https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/are-literature-requests-inherently-off-topic-or-not-constructive though im guessing here as im not one of the downvoters

Answer (score 2):

From my more practical view point (I get paid to make things work), Java is doing this absolutely correctly. Objective-C is the same. Of course they both have a decent default implementation. So what doesn’t make sense to you makes perfect sense to me.

Swift had a bit more time and refined this somewhat. Not any object needs a hash code, and hash codes are intentionally different from one program run to the next. Still, there’s nothing wrong with what Java did.

Comment: It is fair, that this is your opinion, but thats really not what my question is about. I understand, that some people feel like this is a pragmatic solution to a complicated problem. Rather than having a poll of SO user opinions I would much prefer statements of intent from the responsible authorities.

Comment: But it doesn't matter what these people think today. There are no "responsible authorities". There were people who got paid to do a job and did the best job they could do.

Comment: It matters to me, otherwise I would not have asked the question.